# What is min/max depth of a binary tree with n leaf nodes?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I know that the max depth of a binary tree with `n` **nodes** is `n-1`

I know that the max depth of a binary tree with `n` **nodes** is `floor(log2n)`

But what about if I am just given the number of **leaf nodes**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ideals in binary trees.

The ideal "deepest" tree.

```
 *
  *
   *
    *
     a
```

This tree obviously contains one leaf node, and could have an infinite number of intermediate nodes.  This means the maximum depth is unbounded for one leaf node (unless your problem requires internal nodes with more than one child)

The ideal "shallowest" tree

```
          *
      *       *
    *   *   *   *
   a a a a a a a a
```

This tree obviously contains `2^(depth-1)` leaves (for trees of depth 1 or greater), and through the magic of math would have a depth of `log(base2)(leaves) = depth-1` or `1+log(base2)(leaves)`.  Since we can't have a fractional depth, this must be aligned to `ceil(1+log(base2)(leaves))`

To test this, let's build a table

```
leaves formula                        depth
  1    ceil(1+log(base2)(1)) => ceil(1+0) => ceil(1) => 1
  2    ceil(1+log(base2)(2)) => ceil(1+1) => ceil(2) => 2
  3    ceil(1+log(base2)(3)) => ceil(1+1.58) => ceil(2.58) => 3
  4    ceil(1+log(base2)(4)) => ceil(1+2) => ceil(3) => 3
  5    ceil(1+log(base2)(5)) => ceil(1+2.32) => ceil(3.32) => 4
```

and so on.

So the range of depth for a tree with n nodes (where n > 0) is

```
[ceil(1+log(base2)(n)), infinity)
```

unless there are stronger constraints on the deepest tree, like "each internal node must have two siblings (or something like that)"

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out response. It really helped me untangle some wires in my head.

Comment: @AlanSTACK Glad I could help.  The whole process is there so you can leverage the process for future, related problems.  Good luck!